# Is authorizer: aws_iam always required? ( use identity pool, support unauthorized access )

Tags: amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I use Cognito Identity Pool, and allow unauthorized access.
In this case, is authorizer: aws_iam always required? Even for lambda functions that do not require sign-in to execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out and would like to share here for people who have similar confusion.

Based on the concept of Cognito Identity Pool, `authorizer: aws_iam` is always required. You should assign proper policies to each IAM roles to define their accessibilities.

And through `event.requestContext.identity.cognitoAuthenticationType`, you can determine if the invoker is authorized or not. ( its value could be either "authenticated" or "unauthenticated" )

Comment: Found this out by accident. Would love an explanation about why setting unauthenticated users via IAM now requires me to set amplify default config as IAM instead of user pools even for authenticated logins.